# Newline after title in a shadetheorem

Tags: theorems

this is my first question in a Forum like this, so please don't blame me if I do anything wrong :) (correct me if you think I could do something better)

To my question:
How can I insert a newline after a title in a shadetheorem? 
`\newshadetheorem{dfn}{Definition}[chapter]
\definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{shaderulecolor}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\setlength{\shadeboxrule}{5pt}`

.
.
.

`\begin{dfn}[here is a title]
    Some Definition.
\end{dfn}`

so thats my new shade theorem. Is it possible to make a newline after my title?

I hope someone can help me.

Lars

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which package(s) do you use for theorems formatting?

Comment: I used the \usepackage{shadethm}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option using the powerful and flexible `tcolorbox` package.

The important part is

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{dfn}{Definition}%
{colback=shadethmcolor,colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{nitzke}
```

which, referring to Section 14 of the manual, defines a `dfn` theorem-like environment, with syntax:

```
\newtcbtheorem[init options]{name}{display name}{options}{prefix}
```

Here's the output

[image: screenshot]

and a complete MWE to play with:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{dfn}{Definition}%
{colback=shadethmcolor,colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{nitzke}

\begin{document}

\chapter{my chapter}
\begin{dfn}{My title}{mylabel}
here is some text here is some text here is some text; this
definition has label \ref{nitzke:mylabel}
\end{dfn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you're very welcome! :)